# Coordinate problem with \tikzset

Tags: coordinates, tikzset

When using \tikzset the coordinates there are not working as I expected. Why does the red line not start inside the rectangle?
I tried "\tikz \pic at (1,1) {mypic};" instead which does not seem to have an effect.
Writing "\draw [rounded corners] (-1,-1) rectangle (2,2);" produces what I want but I would like to have start the rectangle at (0,0).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\tikzset{
  mypic/.pic = {
     \draw [red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(1.22,1.78)
    (3.68,2.46)};
 }
}

\tikz \pic at (0,0) {mypic};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nested two `tikzpicture`. `\tikz` before `pic` has to be omitted, and the way you composed `pic` is strange. I guess your *mwe* should be as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  mypic/.pic = {
     \draw [red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(1.22,1.78) (3.68,2.46)};
                }
         }
\draw [rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\pic at (0,0) {mypic};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]